# Installing Google.Cloud.Datastore.V1 package on .Net core

Tags: google-cloud-datastore, google-cloud-platform, .net-core

I'm using .netcore 1.0.1 on Ubuntu 16.04. When tying to add the Google.Cloud.Datastore.V1 package to my project (`dotnet add package Goolge.Cloud.Datastore.V1`) I get the following error:

> Unable to resolve 'Google.Cloud.Datastore.V1' for '.NETStandard,Version=v1.5'. The package mentions it support .NetStandard 1.5. I tried installing it with the -Pre tag but dotnet add package doesn't like the -Pre.

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Google.Cloud.Datastore.V1](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Google.Cloud.Datastore.V1) now available only as a prerelease package.  `dotnet add package Google.Cloud.Datastore.V1` tries to install the last released package and so cannot find any suitable one.

As right now `dotnet add` doesn't support `-prerelease` flag, you need to specify prerelease version directly to install it:

```
dotnet add package Google.Cloud.Datastore.V1 -v 1.0.0-beta08
```